# What's the browser compatibility table for CSS import with media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I am looking at https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-3/#media0

```
@import url('style.css') (max-width: 1280px);
```

I've used CanIUse looking for *import* and *media*, but it doesn't detail the combination of the two. There is the [Specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import#Specifications) section on [MDN `import` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) but that doesn't talk about compatibilty and the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import#Browser_compatibility) section on the same page seems to be talking about `import` as a whole, but I can about specifically the addition of media query support with `import`.

The document linked above is dated 2012, but Visual Studio Code yells at me about the syntax used above. It works in my Chrome and I will test with other browsers, too, but it would be great to have a canonical source with a support table.

Comment: I'm pretty sure every browser that supports media queries supports them everywhere that a media type is accepted - including @import. I have not observed any cases in which a browser supporting media queries failed to do so in a situation where it would have otherwise accepted a media type, since media queries are technically an extension of media types. But yes, a canonical source would be great.

Comment: There is no support table for the combination of those two, just like there is no support table for other random features put together. All browsers support @import, you just need to look at the media query support for resolutions which are in my answer.

Comment: I'd actually like to accept @BoltClock answer because I think you are off with the `resolution` thing @Brunis. I did not consider that media queries are extension of media types so what BoltClock is saying answers my questions - I should just go by the support table of media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@import` has supported media types [since CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#at-import). Since media queries are technically an extension of media types (as stated in both CSS2 and MQ3), and there are no known instances of browsers that support media queries not accepting them in places where they would have otherwise accepted a media type (including `@media`, `@import`, and the `media` attribute in HTML), it's probably safe to assume that every browser that supports media queries supports them in `@import`.

A third-party compatibility table would be nice to have, but asking for one is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer and I see how this is off topic so I'm okay to close.

Answer (score 0):

The browser support table on caniuse.com shows IE has partial support from IE9, but with limited support for units (no dppx or dpcm).
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-resolution

Comment: You're looking at the support table for one specific media feature. In other words, the wrong support table.

Comment: @BoltClock not really, this is what he needs for what he is trying to do

Comment: The spec seems to suggest `resolution` deals with screen pixel density. It has its own sections for `width` and `height`. But I was not asking for any subfeature specifically, just assumed there would be a direct support table link as these are not two random features but `import` syntax extension with media queries.